# How to know which page redirected to the login URL with the @login_required decorator in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have two page that the user needs to be logged in to access, both of them redirect to the login URL with the @login_required decorator

```
@login_required
def ask_question(request)
    
@login_required
def answer_question(request)
```

and I would like to display a message on the login page that will be specific depending on the page that redirected to the login.

Both pages have a link on the same page, on the index page so I can't use the request origin because the two have the same origin.

Like:

"You need to be logged in to ask question" (if the user came from the ask question redirection)

"You need to be logged in to answer question" (if the user came from the answer redirection)

Comment: ` {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{% url 'ask_question' id %}">Ask question</a>
            {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Want to ask question?</a>

            {% endif %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `messages` framework of django for both the pages.

For example:

If anybody go on `question` page,from the button say its name `ask question` so make a view for it like :

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required(login_url='/login-route/')
def ask_question(request):
    messages.success(request, 'You need to login to ask the question.')
    context{}
    return render(request,'appname/anyfile.html',context)


@login_required(login_url='/login-route/')
def answer_to_an_question(request):
    context={}
    messages.success(request, 'You need to login to answer the question.')
    return render(request,'appname/anyfile.html',context)
```

You can use any `messages` like `error,success,warning` etc. then it will redirect it to next `url`. Then on `redirected` page where user goes, the message will appear, say its a `login` page where you can show it in format like:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

The best part of using django `messages` is that it will appear only `one` time.

Comment: it seems to make the redirection before making the message and not doing it when i try it. thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')

write your views here

return render(request, 'path/#####.html', context )
```

when user logged in your return will take him to the the page that you want